# App user data not found in usual directores

Tags: applications

Im looking to find the save data of this android rpg game (net.iasolution.fc1sd), but I can neither find its save data folder in **/Android/data/** or **/data/data**. Even though the other apps' folders show up this specific game's folder is not showing up.

Can anyone help me find out whats going on?

Comment: If they're not stored on the public storage, then they're probably stored on the app-specific directory that can only be seen and accessed with root access.

Comment: please note in the linked duplicate /data/data is not mentioned, in the favour of /data/user/0 and /data/user_de/0